# C# generic MVP (VIPER) module: The type ... cannot be used as type parameter 'P' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create base VIPER module, powered by templates. Now it looks like MVP module, but this doesn't matter. My base classes are declared this way.

View:

```
public interface BaseViperView
```

Pesenter:

```
public abstract class BaseViperPresenter<View> 
    where View : BaseViperView
```

Controller (view implementation):

```
public abstract class BaseViperController<P> 
    where P : BaseViperPresenter<BaseViperView>
```

Then I'm trying to create my first module with this classes.

View:

```
public interface AuthorizationView : BaseViperView
```

Presenter:

```
public class AuthorizationPresenter : BaseViperPresenter<AuthorizationView>
```

Controller (view implementation):

```
public class AuthorizationController : BaseViperController<AuthorizationPresenter>
```

And I getting compile error:

> The type 'AuthorizationPresenter' cannot be used as type parameter 'P'
>   in the generic type or method 'BaseViperController< P >'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from 'AuthorizationPresenter' to
>   'BaseViperPresenter'

Where am I wrong?

Comment: MVP stands for **M**odel **V**iew **P**resenter, where did the Controller come from? Also, I highly recommend getting used to start your interfaces names with a capital i - instead of `BaseViperView` use `IBaseViperView`, instead of `AuthorizationView` use `IAuthorizationView`.

Comment: This is just a part of architecture, model exists. Controller is just the name of View implementation, name doesn't matter in this question. About class naming - I'm java programmer, so such naming is more comfortable for me.
My question is still open.